# Issue with simple regex

Tags: regex

i have simple regular expression:

```
^123$
```

Matches are for example

```
123
1234
```

etc.

How can i exactly 123 as result without the 1234 (i'm not sure, if it's possible)?

Comment: '^123$' should *not* match '1234'. In the context of regex, $ matches the end of the line, and in '1234' the end of the line does not follow 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you gave should match only the string `"123"` and should not match `"1234"`. I don't know what you're doing wrong to get it to match `"1234"`, but it's not the regex.

Comment: it seems, that i get both 123 and 1234 as results....so the problem is not in the regex. I must debug now. thanks a lot.

Comment: You could clarify a little - more about what language you're using and what your current code looks like could help us figure out what the problem really is.

Comment: i know, where ist the problem - i have some wrong DB entries.

Answer (score 2):

`^123$` doesn't match 1234 - exactly what you want. So what's the problem?

`^` means start of string to be matched

`$` means end of that string

Comment: i know., but i get more than one result for this.....it seems, that i have a bug :(